# scss prepend selector to current selector

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to prepend a selector directly to the current selector in scss.  Consider the following:

```
.object-fit {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

is there a way to prepend `img` so that the output is `img.object-fit`?

The only way I have seen for prepending is to add `&` after like so:

```
.object-fit {
  img & {
  }
}
```

but this would turn it into a parent child selector: `img .object-fit`

The normal way would be just to append the second selector with `&img` but as this has no dot before the selector, that ends up with a different class name:  `.object-fitimg`

So basically the question is is there anyway inside the object fit class to prepend a bare element selector?

Comment: Did you try `img&`?

Comment: @Blazemonger That's a syntax error in the SCSS parser. `Invalid CSS after "img": expected "{", was "&"

"&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.`

Comment: something like `@at-root img#{&}`?

Comment: @ReSedano Put that as an answer, it works. Good job!

Comment: @ReSedano awesome thanks, add an answer and I'll accept when it lets me

Comment: Ok, you're welcome! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `@at-root` and `&` with interpolation syntax:

```
 .object-fit {
      @at-root img#{&} {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
```

Your output will be:

```
img.object-fit{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Why the `@at-root`? This would be assuming that the goal always is to get out of the current nested selector.

Comment: @Trollsyn if I don't use the `@at-root` it compiles to `.object-fit img.object-fit`

Comment: @Trollsyn no problem! :-)

Comment: There seem to be limits to this approach, at-root target can only apply to the first selector listed, see https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2059

Answer (score 1):

Complete answer here is `@at-root selector-append()`, which will also work for multiple parent selectors.

Source: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2059#issuecomment-218862922

```css
.object-fit,
.non-fit {
  @at-root #{selector-append("img", &)} {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Output

```css
img.object-fit, img.non-fit {
  color: blue;
}
```