# Trying to get section.class1 instead of section .class1, scss

Tags: css, sass, selector

I am trying to compile the scss so i get the section when it has the class1. I can't figure it out how to do it as i get the space and it doesn't work the same.

Current output:

```
.class2 > section .class1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Desired output:

```
.class2 > section.class1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Scss:

```
.class1 {
    .class2 > section & {
            margin: 0;
    }  
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="class2">
  <section class="class1"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try without space, like `.class2 > section& {`? If that doesn't work, you probably won't be able to achieve what you want due to limitation described in first `Heads up` section here -> https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

Comment: yes, that doesn't work and i think you are right. I will need to try something else due to structural limitation in my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scss prepend selector to current selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270726/scss-prepend-selector-to-current-selector)

Comment: yes, that's perfect! Thank you. this worked: .class1 {
    @at-root .class2 > section#{&} {
            margin: 0;
    }  
  }

Answer (score 0):

Please take reference from below code, or visit : https://jsfiddle.net/tc4b93kj/1/:

```
.class2 > section {
        &.class1 {
           margin: 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.class2 {
        > section{
        &.class1{
         margin: 0;
         }

        }  
  }
```

Comment: I can't change the structure, it all needs to be within the scope of class1 as it is now.

Comment: Show your html then PLease!

Comment: I did, class2 is just a shell. It can have other type of sections inside so that's why i have a scope that styles the class1. So i can't have the shell changed global, just when it has the section with that class it will change the section

Comment: If i am not worng then remove outer selector and use `        section{
        &.class1{
         margin: 0;
         }

        } `